Camera Permission automatically denied on xcode simulator
I am very new to this so please bear with me.
I am trying to build an app(Flutter) using Andriod studio, that scans qr codes of guest the code works fine on andriod but on IOS it is not working, as the camera permission is denied automatically when I click on start scanning.Camera permission denied
Here is my main.dart
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
   import 'guest_list.dart';

     void main() {
     runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GuestListProvider(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
   );
}

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Guest Check-In App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
    );
   }
  }

   class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Enter'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}`

and my guest_list.dart
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
  import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';
  import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

 class GuestListProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _guestList = [
    'John Doe',
    'Jane Smith',
    'Alice Johnson',
  ];

  final Set<String> _checkedInGuests = Set();

  List<String> get guestList => _guestList;

  bool isCheckedIn(String guest) {
    return _checkedInGuests.contains(guest);
  }

  void checkInGuest(String guest) {
    _checkedInGuests.add(guest);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Guest Check-In'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/flowery_background.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                color: Colors.white30.withOpacity(0.3),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GuestListView(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    PermissionStatus status = await _getCameraPermission();
                    if (status.isGranted) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QRViewExample()),
                      );
                    } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                      // Handle permission permanently denied scenario
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Camera Permission Denied'),
                          content: Text('Camera permission is required to scan QR codes. Please enable it in the settings.'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                openAppSettings();
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('Open Settings'),
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('Cancel'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      // Handle other permission denied scenarios
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Camera Permission Denied'),
                          content: Text('Camera permission is required to scan QR codes.'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('OK'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Start Scanning'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getCameraPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      final result = await Permission.camera.request();
      return result;
    } else {
      return status;
    }
  }
}

class GuestListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GuestListProvider>(
      builder: (context, guestListProvider, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: guestListProvider.guestList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final guest = guestListProvider.guestList[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(guest),
              trailing: guestListProvider.isCheckedIn(guest)
                  ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
                  : null,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class QRViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _QRViewExampleState();
}

class _QRViewExampleState extends State<QRViewExample> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  QRViewController? controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Scan QR Code')),
      body: QRView(
        key: qrKey,
        onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
        overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          borderColor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderLength: 30,
          borderWidth: 10,
          cutOutSize: 300,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      final guestName = scanData.code;
      final guestListProvider = Provider.of<GuestListProvider>(context, listen: false);
      if (guestName != null) {
        if (guestListProvider.guestList.contains(guestName)) {
          if (guestListProvider.isCheckedIn(guestName)) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Already Checked In'),
                content: Text('$guestName has already been checked in.'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            guestListProvider.checkInGuest(guestName);
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Guest Checked In'),
                content: Text('$guestName has been checked in.'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Return to guest list
                    },
                    child: Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        } else {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Guest Not Found'),
              content: Text('$guestName is not on the guest list.'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Return to guest list
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


I have tried using the setting.bundle to make the app show up in settings on the simulator but so far i can not still grant permissison to the app. If I remove the permission handler and click start scanning now it just opens a blank white page with the square box  and then I get this error
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, A UIKitView widget is trying to create a PlatformView with an unregistered type: < net.touchcapture.qr.flutterqr/qrview >, If you are the author of the PlatformView, make sure registerViewFactory is invoked.
See: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views#on-the-platform-side-1 for more details.
If you are not the author of the PlatformView, make sure to call GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register., null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      PlatformViewsService.initUiKitView (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:243:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _DarwinViewState._createNewUiKitView (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:918:36)
<asynchronous suspension>

Here is my AppDelegate.swift code:
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

blank camera page
My Info.plist has:
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires camera access to scan QR codes.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires microphone access for scanning QR codes.</string>


@Paulw11 even though camera is not available on simulator, with native code the permissions dialog would show up if the app is configured correctly. So my guess it's a flutter limitation.

Have you previously responded to the permissions dialog on that simulator with a "deny" response?  The app only gets to ask once. Check the app's permissions in settings on the simulator. Try deleting the app from the simulator

No, I have not.
